# Windows Azure Mobile Services management API

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Is there any management API in Windows Azure Mobile Services?
For example: methods to create mobile services or data tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Mobile Service Management API however it is not publicly available yet. One thing you could do is take a look at the source code for Windows Azure CLI tools and figure out how this API has been implemented. You can view the source code on GitHub: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools-xplat.